# "should" query affect scoring, how to avoid that?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to change the following ElasticSearch so the "should" array will not affect the scoring of the result. I want that the score will be calculated by the "query_string" for the name property only.

how can i achieve that with minimum chnages

```
GET customers/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "default_field": "properties.name",
                        "query": "Joe*"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [                    
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.role": "admin"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.role": "sysop"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.role": "client"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "public"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "public"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "hide_from_search_results"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "deleted"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "banned"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "hide_from_search_results"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "deleted"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "banned"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "hide_from_search_results"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "deleted"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "properties.status": "banned"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 30,
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_script": {
                "type": "string",
                "order": "desc",
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "source": "return doc['_index'][0] == 'customers' && doc.containsKey('properties.videoCount')?doc['properties.videoCount'].value:0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_script": {
                "type": "string",
                "order": "desc",
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "source": "long timestampNow = new Date().getTime(); return doc['_index'][0] == 'customers' && doc.containsKey('properties.subscriptions.features.allow-application')?(timestampNow < doc['properties.subscriptions.features.first-on-search'].value.getMillis()):false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_script": {
                "type": "string",
                "order": "desc",
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "source": "return doc['_index'][0] == 'customers' && doc.containsKey('properties.videoCount')?doc['properties.videoCount'].value:0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [bool should and filter clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to achieve your required result.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "properties":{
    "name": "Joe",
    "role":"sysop"
  }
}
{
  "properties":{
    "name": "Joe",
    "role":"admin"
  }
}
{
  "properties":{
    "name": "Joe",
    "role":"student"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "properties.name",
            "query": "Joe*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "properties.role": "student"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "properties.role": "sysop"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65469210",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "role": "admin"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65469210",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "role": "student"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65469210",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "role": "sysop"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**You can even use the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html), to know how the score is calculated. Here you can see that the `should` clauses match have a value of 0.0. Therefore, they do not contribute in the overall scoring of the query.**

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": "[65469210][0]",
        "_node": "g1iQ5TpzQli7sSx266LDEA",
        "_index": "65469210",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "role": "admin"
          }
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1.0,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1.0,
              "description": "properties.name:joe*",
              "details": []
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[65469210][0]",
        "_node": "g1iQ5TpzQli7sSx266LDEA",
        "_index": "65469210",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "role": "student"
          }
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1.0,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1.0,
              "description": "properties.name:joe*",
              "details": []
            },
            {
              "value": 0.0,                  // note this
              "description": "ConstantScore(properties.role:student properties.role:sysop)^0.0",
              "details": []
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard": "[65469210][0]",
        "_node": "g1iQ5TpzQli7sSx266LDEA",
        "_index": "65469210",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "role": "sysop"
          }
        },
        "_explanation": {
          "value": 1.0,
          "description": "sum of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 1.0,
              "description": "properties.name:joe*",
              "details": []
            },
            {
              "value": 0.0,                // note this
              "description": "ConstantScore(properties.role:student properties.role:sysop)^0.0",
              "details": []
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The query returns also records not included in the "should" block. for instance properties.role = 'User'. somehow the should ignored...

Comment: @Omtechguy like in the above example index data I used, do you want that the document containing `"role":"admin"` should not include in the search result ?

Comment: I fixed it by removing the other should and bool wrappers of the filter section in your answer. Please update your answer if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter, filter just remove documents, and wont affect the score:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

Comment: But how can i use should in the filter? Should i add "should" thete? Can you revise my example?

Comment: Well ESCoder just do it !